AutoDesk Premium Reporting APIs returns 403 Error when using 3-legged authentication
I'm trying to use Premium Reporting API using 3-legged token. When I call endpoints such as

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/insights/v1/usage-queries
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/insights/v1/contexts

I'm getting 403 Forbidden error with the following response body:
    {
      "title": "ForbiddenError",
      "detail": ""
    }

I'm using free trial version and my user has secondary admin role.
I followed steps described here https://get-started.aps.autodesk.com/ (created app and custom integration in ACC), after that I was able to obtain 3-legged token.
I've found this answer about PAT tokens: Autodesk Premium reporting API: Is the 3-way auth token the only way to access the usage endpoint?. Surprisingly it worked with combination of PAT and 2-legged tokens.
Why 3-legged token is not working, but PAT + 2-legged is working?
